# generating new csv files from a single csv file if it matches start and stop strings python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a long csv file that I want to use to generate several csv files by matching a start flag

```
flag, DATA
new ,
    ,data1
    ,data2
    ,.....
new ,
    ,data3
    ,data4
    ,.....
new ,
    ,data5
    ,data6
    ,.....
```

I want to generate new csv files:

```
data1.csv  data2.csv  data3.csv
                  
data1      data3         data5
data2      data4         data6
.....      .....         .....
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def my_func(fname):
    sns = []

    flag = True
 
    with open(fname) as csvfile:
        tdr_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in tdr_reader:
            if 'new' in row and flag:
                sns.append('new_file')
                flag = False
                continue
            elif 'new' in row and not flag:
                sns.append('new_file')
                flag = True
                continue
            elif '' in row and flag:
                flag = False
            if not flag:
                sns.append(row)
                #print(sns)
    return sns

>>>my_func(file_name)
['new_file',['data1','data2'], 'new_file',['data3','data4'], 'new_file',['data5','data6']]
```

Not sure where to go from here.  Basically I want to create a new csv file for every entry on the list so the first csv file should be `new_file1.csv` as the name and `'data1'` and `'data2'` as it's contents and the next one as `new_file2.csv` and `'data3'` and `'data4'` as it's contents...etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps:**

1. Iterate through the lines of the source csv file.
2. When the flag `new` is encountered, open a new csv file with the current file index.
3. As long as the current row isn't the flag `new`, continue writing to the currently opened file.
4. If the flag `new` is encountered again, repeat step 2
5. Note that instead of storing to an intermediate variable e.g. `sns` in your case, we would just write it automatically to the output file as it is more efficient. So, if we ever load a gigabyte-sized csv, we don't have to store it in memory, we would just read line by line and directly write each iterated line to the output file, no need to store anything.

   - If this doesn't fit your use case, you can change this behavior. Let me know should you need help.

### Solution 1:

Manually iterate through the lines of the file via `next()` to have control on when to open a new file.

```
import csv

def my_func(fname):
    flag_indicator = 'new'
    new_file_name = "./new_file{index}.csv"
    index = 1

    with open(fname) as csvfile:
        tdr_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

        while (row := next(tdr_reader, None)) and row[0] != flag_indicator:
            pass

        while row:
            with open(new_file_name.format(index=index), 'w') as new_file:
                new_file_writer = csv.writer(new_file)
                index += 1
                while (row := next(tdr_reader, None)) and row[0] != flag_indicator:
                    new_file_writer.writerow(row[1:])

my_func('./input.csv')
```

### Solution 2:

Manually call `open()` and `close()` on the file.

```
import csv

def my_func(fname):
    flag_indicator = 'new'
    new_file_name = "./new_file{index}.csv"
    index = 1

    with open(fname) as csvfile:
        tdr_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        new_file = None
        new_file_writer = None

        for row in tdr_reader:
            if row[0] == flag_indicator:
                if new_file:
                    new_file.close()
                new_file = open(new_file_name.format(index=index), 'w')
                new_file_writer = csv.writer(new_file)
                index += 1
            elif new_file is None:
                continue
            else:
                new_file_writer.writerow(row[1:])

my_func('./input.csv')
```

**Result of both solutions**

```
$ tree
.
├── input.csv
├── new_file1.csv
├── new_file2.csv
├── new_file3.csv
└── script.py

0 directories, 5 files
$ cat input.csv 
flag, DATA
new,
    ,data1
    ,data2
new,
    ,data3
    ,data4
new,
    ,data5
    ,data6
$ cat new_file1.csv 
data1
data2
$ cat new_file2.csv 
data3
data4
$ cat new_file3.csv 
data5
data6
```